# Limit related problems in differentiation

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Find
$$\lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{1-\cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-\alpha)^2}$$

Please help me to solve this calculus problem

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Your image is barely readable. Since the question is so short, how about type it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: What kind of rules can you use?

Comment: Instead of suggesting an edit from a different account, please use your original account and click on "edit" to add details to your question. As it stands, it is not possible if the suggested edit is by you or by someone else pretending to be you. On a side note, using your original account, you can add comments to your own posts irrespective of reputation.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{1-\cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-\alpha)^2}=\frac{1-\cos[a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)]}{a^2(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^2}a^2(x-\beta)^2$$

then refer to standard limit as $t\to 0$

$$\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\to \frac12$$

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1-\cos t}{t^2} = \frac12$.

We have

$$\frac{1-\cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-\alpha)^2} = \frac{1-\cos[a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)]}{(x-\alpha)^2} = \frac{1-\cos[a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)]}{[a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)]^2}\cdot a^2(x-\beta)^2 \xrightarrow{x\to\alpha} \frac12a^2(\alpha-\beta)^2$$

Comment: @MathOverview Yes. Check that $$ax^2+bx+ c = a\left(x - \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(x - \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Use the Taylor series of 
$$
\cos(a(x-\alpha)(x+\beta))
$$
around $\alpha$. That is 
$$
\cos(a(x-\alpha)(x+\beta))= 1-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)^2(x-\alpha)^2a^2+o((x-\alpha)^3)
$$